# Django WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/chat/8_9/' failed:

Tags: python, django, websocket, redis, channel

I am doing a Django project in which I have added a live chat feature using Django channels. When I finished the messaging part I worked on other parts of the project (like posting, liking posts, and in general parts that have nothing to do with the messaging). However now when I test the messaging page I get the following error in my browser console:

```
8_9:58 WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/chat/8_9/' failed:
```

The error has no further explanation after the colon (which is why I don't even know where to start solving it, I've had similar errors but they always had something else after the colon). I also tried rolling back to an older version of my app using GitHub (I went back to the last version that I was sure was working) and it still didn't work.

Here is my js code:

```
        const roomName = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('room-name').textContent);

        var chatSocket = "";

        if(document.location.protocol == "https:"){
            chatSocket = new WebSocket(
                'wss://'
                + window.location.host
                + '/wss/chat/'
                + roomName
                + '/'
            );
        }
        else{
            chatSocket = new WebSocket(
                'ws://'
                + window.location.host
                + '/ws/chat/'
                + roomName
                + '/'
            );
        }

        chatSocket.addEventListener('open', function(event) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/ajax/get_msg/',
                data: {
                  'room': roomName
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                  var realData=data[0];
                  var i=0;
                  while(i<realData.length){
                    document.querySelector('#chat-log').value += (realData[i][0] + ': ' + realData[i][1] + '\n');
                    i++;
                  }
                }
            });
        })

        chatSocket.onmessage = function(e) {
            const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
            document.querySelector('#chat-log').value += (data.user + ': ' + data.message + '\n');
        };

        chatSocket.onclose = function(e) {
            console.error('Chat socket closed unexpectedly');
        };

        document.querySelector('#chat-message-input').focus();
        document.querySelector('#chat-message-input').onkeyup = function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 13) {  // enter, return
                document.querySelector('#chat-message-submit').click();
            }
        };

        document.querySelector('#chat-message-submit').onclick = function(e) {
            const messageInputDom = document.querySelector('#chat-message-input');
            const message = messageInputDom.value;
            chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
                'message': message,
            }));
            messageInputDom.value = '';
        };
```

My routing:

```
# Django imports
from django.urls import re_path
from . import consumers

# routing to the consumer
websocket_urlpatterns=[
    re_path(r'wss/chat/(?P<room_name>\w+)/$', consumers.ChatConsumer),
    re_path(r'ws/chat/(?P<room_name>\w+)/$', consumers.ChatConsumer),
]
```

My consumer:

```
import json
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from .models import Message

User = get_user_model()


class ChatConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_name
        # Join room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        self.accept()

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        # Leave room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    # Receive message from WebSocket
    def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']

        # get both users
        user = self.scope["user"]
        get_ids = self.scope["url_route"]["kwargs"]["room_name"]
        ids = get_ids.split('_')
        my_user = User.objects.get(username=user.username)
        my_id = my_user.id
        other_id = 0
        if str(ids[0]) == str(my_id):
            other_id = ids[1]
        else:
            other_id = ids[0]
        other_user = User.objects.get(pk=other_id)

        # save the sent message to a database
        new_message = Message(sender=my_user, rec=other_user, text=message, room=get_ids)
        new_message.save()

        # Send message to room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'chat_message',
                'message': message,
                'user': user.username,
            }
        )

    # Receive message from room group
    def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']
        # get the user that sent the message
        user = event['user']
        # Send message to WebSocket
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message,
            'user': user
        }))
```

And my settings:

```
CACHES = {
    "default": {
         "BACKEND": "redis_cache.RedisCache",
         "LOCATION": REDIS_URI,
    }
}
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [REDIS_URI],
        },
    },
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated